# askpass only for tunneled requests

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'd quite like to have the confirm (`ssh-add -c keyfile`) behaviour from ssh-agent- but only for requests that are tunneled over ssh (`ssh -A richo@somewhere`).

Is this possible? The manpage seems to suggest not, unless I somehow work out how to start two agents and add to one without the confirm flag and one without the other. That's what I'll do if there's no simple solution.